# Listen to all SMSes and do something when the definite message is received in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, sms

I want my android app to listen in all incoming messages and do what it is supposed to do when it receives the intended message. For example, I want to send the location of the phone to a preset number when it receives the message that the phone is missing, I do not care from which number it receives the message, only the message that will sent should be send to the specified number (for example my second number).
I wrote the messaging codes and they are in the program and my only problem is receiving the messages and distinguishing them from each other and separating the correct message.

I apologize if my question is superficial or my explanation is inaccurate. I'm new in Xamarin and I have not become a professional yet. If the explanation is not complete, tell me where the problem is, I will explain more. Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell you what the problem is, there is no actual code that presents a problem. From what I have read, seems doable, but it is unlikely that coding you could enable the GPS on if it was already off.

Comment: Yes. It turns on GPS if it has permission to change system settings,. And if it fails, it sends the last location in the phone memory. But this isn't the point. I just want to receive all the SMSes and see what is written in it. And if there was a message it was waiting for, do its job. I thought that each message could be saved in a string and then check the string. So, like the command line, I can send commands remotely via SMS.

Comment: You are missing the code you are having trouble with. Probably others will help you if they see what you actually did so they can give you an answer that will be useful to you.

Comment: I don't have even one line code for receiving SMS. Now I can just send SMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `BroadcastReceiver`(`android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`) to listener the SMSes.

For more detail information, please refer to the official document: [Broadcast Receivers in Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers).

Something like:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" })]
class SMSBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static string IntentAction = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       if (intent.Action != SmsRetriever.SmsRetrievedAction)
        return;

       var extrasBundleundle = intent.Extras;
       if (extrasBundleundle == null) return;
       var status = (Statuses)extrasBundleundle.Get(SmsRetriever.ExtraStatus);
       switch (status.StatusCode)
         {
            case CommonStatusCodes.Success:
            // Get SMS message contents
            var messageContent = (string)extrasBundleundle.Get(SmsRetriever.ExtraSmsMessage);
            
              break;

            case CommonStatusCodes.Timeout:
            
              break;
         }          
    }
}
```

don't forget to add the permission
`<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS”/>`

Comment: Thank you so much!